# How to redirect WP post with a specific word in the URL

Tags: urls, htaccess

I've changed the URL structure of my WordPress post (not page) from:

```
example.com/archive/post-id
```

to:

```
example.com/post-name
```

I'd like to redirect the old structure `/post/` to the new one via `.htaccess`, or plugin.

Comment: Please take a look at `WP_Rewrite` and search the [tag:rewrite] archives on this page. Show us your research and your efforts to solve this problem and where exactly you're stuck.

Comment: If xxxxx would be your post-name I don't know what the problem is, because my WordPress installation redirects from /archive/post-name to /post-name by itself. Could you show us more?

Comment: @Scuba Kay the xxxxx is id number of post not post name, my problem is my post archive in google like `example.com/archive/xxxxx` and i am change my link like `example.com/post-nam` . so when any user opne my site from google its show him 401 error

Answer (score 0):

Try using wp_rewrite:

```
add_action('init', 'flush_rewrite_rules');

function custom_add_rewrite_rules( $wp_rewrite ) {
    $new_rules = array( 
        'archive/(\d+)' => '/?p=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1)
    );
    $wp_rewrite->rules = $new_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', 'custom_add_rewrite_rules');
```

Use the plugin activation hook for the flush_rewrite_rules, because you only want this to happen all the time while developing. In production this should only happen when activating your plugin.

For more about flush_rewrite_rules: [flush_rewrite_rules @ WordPress.org](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules)

Comment: what you mean about `index.php?p=` its for post or page ?? my problem for post

Comment: That's just a typo.

Comment: It is not a good idea to fresh and generate the rewrite rules on each activation, if WP was fired, only on plugin activation is it fine.

Comment: That's what I meant.

Comment: so what can i do ??

Comment: i will use your code and put it in `function.php` and save it, then go to `http://www.cccc.net/hellow-world` its not open. but when change permalink to `http://www.roqiah.net/archives/1064` its open what can i do

Comment: Do you have any experience in plugin development? Then you can create a plugin and add this function to it. If you have no experience, I suggest you start reading [here] (http://codex.wordpress.org/). If you don't fancy coding anything at all, you could always find [a] (http://wordpress.org/plugins/quick-pagepost-redirect-plugin/) [plugin] (http://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/) [that] (http://wordpress.org/plugins/eps-301-redirects/) [does] (http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-seo-redirect-301/) the work for you.

Comment: @Scuba Kay  woow i have 1258 post in my site and i canot use this plugin http://wordpress.org/plugins/quick-pagepost-redirect-plugin